# What does "no visual interruption" for notification importance mean?

Tags: notifications, 8.0-oreo

When configuring notification categories, you can change the **Importance** to *Urgent*, *High*, *Medium*, and *Low*. The description for *Low* says "No sound or visual interruption." What does no visual interruption mean? I want to set certain notifications to the lowest possible, but I still want them showing in the notification bar, so if no visual interruption means that it will disappear from my notification bar, then I'll leave it at *Medium*.

Comment: I assume that, as the answerer said, those notifications will be visible in the notification bar, but not pop up above what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No visual interruption means that the notification won't peak at the top of your screen. It will still show up in the notification bar.

https://www.androidcentral.com/notification-channels - This article further confirms that setting notification importance to Low just means you will not be getting any indication that you have received a notification, the notification will still show up in the Notification Bar though.

The only way a notification would not show up in the Notification Bar would be if you completely disabled notifications for an app.